# powershell could not create ssl/tsl secure

Tags: powershell

I'm using a powershell script to download and execute a file, but since some time I go I get a could not create ssl/tsl secure channel.

```
$down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; 
$url = 'url'; 
$file = 'file';
$down.DownloadFile($url,$file); 
$exec = New-Object -com shell.application; 
$exec.shellexecute($file); 
exit;
```

Answer (score 36):

TLS 1.2 should be enabled to get it working. In PowerShell you can find out which protocols your system supports by running this code:

```
[Enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType]) -contains 'Tls12'
```

If the result is True then your system supports TLS 1.2. You can find out which protocols are being used by running:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.HasFlag([Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12)
```

If the result is True then TLS 1.2 is being used . However, you can add TLS 1.2 explicitly by using:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

This should solve these problems.

Comment: Was trying to install chocolately and ran to this error. This worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped you.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It works.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 25):

It may be that the site you are connection to requires TLS 1.2, whereas powershell uses TLS 1.0 by default (if I remember correctly)

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = 'https://github.com/mpdairy/posh.git'
$file = 'C:\ExistingDirectory\test.git'
$down.DownloadFile($url,$file)
$exec = New-Object -com shell.application
$exec.shellexecute($file)
exit
```

Without using Tls 1.2, I get this error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS
secure channel."
At line:1 char:1
+ $down.DownloadFile($url,$file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Comment: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:5 char:1
+ $down.DownloadFile($url,$file)

I'm getting this error now , I'm using github to host my file and direct download it

Comment: @katemaran Does the `$url` use `http` or `https`? What happens when you manually paste the url into a web browser?

Comment: The website uses https it's Github , if  i paste the url it downloads the file

Comment: @katemaran That's odd. See edit - just tested it with a git file; works for me with Tls 1.2, not without. Do you need to provide guthub credentials? Is the path valid and directory present?

Comment: It used to work without a specified path , what is the default download path in the script I used above? Also the file I use is an executable if that matters

Comment: @katemaran No idea. [Documentation specifies two arguments are required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's possible to set **Tls12** as permanent default for all scripts by [adding that first line to your profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/): `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error trying to install Wiki.js in Windows server. The issue was the ps1 script included TLS 1.1 as a fallback. The steps below can be changed for any other powershell install

To fix this;

1. I downloaded the install.ps1 file from installation instructions on [Wiki.js installation](https://docs.requarks.io/wiki/install/installation#run-wiki-js)

   iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://wiki.js.org/install.ps1'))
2. Removed "tls11, tls" from the first line

   From:

   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"

   To:

   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"
3. Saved the file in a local directory and changed directory (CD) into
   the local directory Ran the command
   "iex .\install.ps1"

It's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample code. I written this couple of years when Terraform moved to TLS.

```
$source=<folder where file suppose to be present>
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Downloading Terraform Required"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::TLS12
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
if ((test-path "${source}\terraform.zip") -eq $false) {
    $wc.downloadfile("https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.2/terraform_0.11.2_windows_amd64.zip","${source}\terraform.zip")
}
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$source\terraform.zip", $destination)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem just before and how I fixed it is by changing the link. Make sure the page you're trying to download is a RAW file, for example -

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TTT2866/Batch-username-generator/master/username_generator.bat`

and not

`https://github.com/TTT2866/Batch-username-generator/blob/master/username_generator.bat`

Note the "raw" in the first link