Using Start-Process to install Windows HLK
I'm trying to install Windows HLK in startup-script. The script exits silently right after it launches Start-Process on the installer(no exception is thrown). Here's my original script:
function Install-WindowsHLK {
    param (
      [string]$downloadUrl = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2289283'
    )
    
    $downloadPath = 'C:\temp'
    mkdir $downloadPath
    $fullPath = Join-Path $downloadPath 'HLKSetup.exe'
    $hlkUser = 'hlk'
    $hlkPassword = 'Password1'
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $hlkPassword -AsPlainText -Force    
   
    Write-Host 'Creating a new user account to install Windows HLK'
    New-LocalUser -Name $hlkUser -Description 'HLK test user' -Password $secpasswd

    Write-Host 'Adding the new user account to the Administrators group'
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member $hlkUser
  
    Write-Host 'Downloading Windows HLK installer'
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadUrl -OutFile $fullPath
    
    Write-Host 'Giving the new user account full control over the HLK installer'
    $acl = Get-Acl $fullPath
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($hlkUser, 'FullControl', 'Allow')
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl $fullPath $acl


   
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Value 0
  
    Write-Host 'Executing Windows HLK installer'
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($hlkUser, $secpasswd)
    Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /q /norestart' -Wait
  }
  
  try {
    # Explicitly turning on TLS 1.2 protocol (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389502)
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Install-WindowsHLK
  }
  catch {
    Write-Host "BuildFailed: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
  }

To debug, I tried the following:

Copied the same script in Powershell ISE('New Script', paste, then F5). It launches the installer successfully(/q installation but I can see installing processes in task manager)
On the system which already has the installer downloaded and new user created, I tried:


Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /q /norestart' -Wait in Powershell ISE's console pane, succeeds.
Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /q /norestart' -Wait in a 'Windows PowerShell' console(search powershell, right click and run as Administrator), exits silently. ($mycreds and $fullPath were set correctly, just skipped the new user creation lines)
Run Start-Process -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /q /norestart' -Wait in a 'Windows PowerShell' console, succeeds.
Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe' -ArgumentList 'microsoft.com' -Wait in a 'Windows PowerShell' console, succeeds.
Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath 'notepad' -ArgumentList 'microsoft.com' -Wait in a 'Windows PowerShell' console, succeeds.
Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /norestart' -Wait in Powershell ISE's console pane, succeeds. This is without the /q param, so installer UI shows up.
Run Start-Process -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList '/features + /norestart' -Wait in a 'Windows PowerShell' console. This is without the /q param, but no installer UI shows up, exits silently.
Tried various options the installer provides(HLKSetup.exe /? shows all the options), for example 'HLKSetup.exe /list' - same behavior - doesn't run in 'Windows PowerShell' console with -Credential option.

It looks like it has something to do with the installer itself(ping.exe and notepad.exe both work no matter how it's run), but how/where it runs is also a factor (works in ISE, not in console or startup-script)? Does someone have experiences/good reasoning for these? Better yet, some workarounds that I can try? Thanks!
(My previously asked question on this same topic was closed due to typo, so asking again, with more details)

Just to point out a general pitfall when using Start-Process -Credential (it doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem in your case): By default, the caller's working dir. is also used by the target process, which can fail, namely if the target user doesn't have permission to access that directory (a problem that the obsolescent ISE may mask). The solution is to use the -WorkingDirectory parameter with a directory path that the target user is permitted to use, e.g. C:\

Is the google-compute-engine tag relevant here? If so, please edit your question to explain why.

@mklement0, this Windows instance is on Google Computer Engine, and eventually I need it to run as https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows. However, the current issue probably will repro everywhere though(I don't have any other Windows instance at hands to verify).
And yes, I forgot to mention I also tried -WorkingDirectory 'C:\temp', that did  not help.
